# How can I subscribe to valueChanges of a standalone input?

Tags: angular

If within a parent form I have a standalone form field like the below (without a `formcontrolName`). How can I subscribe to its `valueChanges` property?

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label for="userName">Name</mat-label>
 <input id="userName" 
   [ngModel]="name" 
   (ngModelChange)="updateName($event)" 
   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some time ago (I think that in Angular 6) a NgModel has internally a NgControl. So you can simply use a template reference variable (e.g. input)

```
<input id="userName"  #input
   [ngModel]="name" 
   (ngModelChange)="name=$event" 
   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
```

And use `read:NgControl`

```
  //If is always visible you use static:true
  //else you subscribe in ngAfterOnInit

  @ViewChild('input',{static:true,read:NgControl}) input
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.input.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

But..., why not use a FormControl that not belong to the FormGroup

```
<input id="userName" [formControl]="myFormControl"..>

//in .ts
myFormControl=new FormControl();

ngOnInit(){
   this.myFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(...)
}
```

Or use the function updateName?

Comment: I have to use `debounceTime` on it. But yea, I didn't know I could do the latter within a form. Thanks.